# How to store null in a double field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongodb schema has a field of "double" data type. Sometimes, when there is no value for this field, mongo is storing it as 0.0 but I need it to store as null

1. `db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": null })` - When inserted, schema validation fails (which is expected)
2. `db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": Number(null) })` - When inserted, stores as 0.0 (`"salary" : 0.0`)
3. `db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": Number() })` - When inserted, stores as 0.0 (`"salary" : 0.0`)
4. `db.nulltest.insertOne({ "name": "abc", "salary": Number("null") })` - When inserted, stored as NaN (`"salary" : NaN`)

My Schema:

```
db.createCollection("nulltest", {
validator: { $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: "object",
    properties: {
        "name": {
            bsonType: "string"
        },
        "salary": {
            bsonType: "double"
            }
        }}
    }} )
```

Question: How can I store null value in a field of double data type? ie: `"salary": null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array for `bsonType`. For example:

```
db.createCollection("test", {
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: ["num"],
      properties: {
        num: {
          bsonType: [ "double", "null" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This schema should accept `double` or `null`:

```
> db.test.insert({_id: 0, num: 123})
> db.test.insert({_id: 1, num: null})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 0, "num": 123 }
{ "_id": 1, "num": null }
```

All possible types are outlined in [BSON types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

Note that `null` is a separate type. `Number(null)` doesn't make sense from types point of view. It's like saying `Number(String)`.

Comment: Is it required to have quotes around null?

Comment: For the `bsonType` I believe so.